# How to call a method in the class I am testing in Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium

In Robotium, say I am testing a class called `ClassA`. I want to test the functionality of a method in `ClassA`, say `Method1`. How would I call `Method1` in Robotium?

Edit:
So I was looking around the solo methods and I seem to found a solution using reflection but I am still wondering if there's an easier solution. I'm not that familiar with Robotium but in junit you can easily call `method1` in the test method. In robotium, it's saying that the method is undefined.

From `ClassA`

```
public void method1(String str) {
    // Do something
}
```

From `ClassATest`

```
public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
    Method m = solo.getCurrentActivity().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("method1", String.class);
    m.invoke(solo.getCurrentActivity(), str);
}
```

Comment: That's not the typical way you use robotium. Instead of testing classes and methods, robotium simulates user actions and verifies that an app responded correctly to the user action. Can your users do something that invokes method1? If so, you can write a test where robotium automates that user action for you.

Comment: No. What I was trying to do was testing a function that deals with time. After midnight, the data should reset. Method1 was called to change the time so that I can see if the data actually resets the next day

Comment: Well in that case, if you have access to the app's source code you can simplify by typecasting. ((MyActivity) solo.getCurrentActivity()).method1(str);

Comment: Thanks, that was more simpler than my answer. Would you like to answer it so I can pick your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify by typecasting.

```
((MyActivity) solo.getCurrentActivity()).method1(str);
```